# excel-parser is not working when running the application through node-window

Tags: excel, node.js

I am parsing the excel(xsl and xslx) using node module excel-parser.And i deployed the application using node-window node module.

The node-modules i am using:

https://github.com/vxtindia/excel-parser

It throw the error:

```
code: 1
killed: false
signal: null
```

It is working if i start the application normally (node `server.js`)

I installed the dependencies also for the `excel-parser`:

https://github.com/vxtindia/excel-parser/wiki

```
excelParser.parse({
      inFile: path.join(exports.rootpath,'/public/data/bizsteps/users/',util.getCurrentUser(req),'/temp/','temperatureLog'+extension),
      worksheet: 1,
      skipEmpty: true
    },function(err, records){ 
      if(err) {
        callback(err,null)
      }else{
          _.each(records,function(element,index){records[index]=_.object(["time","temperature"], [parseFloat(element[0]),parseFloat(element[1])]); });
          callback(null,records);             
      }
    });
```

The above is my code.Can any one help me out what was the problem and any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the python command from shell explicitly (it shown in the node exception), 
something like:

```
python /home/michael/projects/some-project/node_modules/excel-parser/convert.py -x /tmp/test.xls
```

And see what error it gives you and you can take it from there.
In my case I had to install xlrd package. If it is the same case simply:
Download xlrd zip from here:

https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/x/xlrd/xlrd-0.7.1.zip#md5=851bd20873224d97cfb5ccca2d22b81c

2) unzip

3) cd to dir

4) sudo python setup.py install